# HTTP 500 error from self-hosted WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a self hosted WCF server that, after it's been running for a while on a particular system, starts returning HTTP 500 errors.  The return body is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Internal Server Error</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Internal Server Error</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 500. An internal server error has occured.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

The method body that it fails on is a simple as can be:

```
public Version GetServerAdminVersion()
{
    return ServiceMain._AdminVer;
}
```

This code normally works fine (restarting the process causes it to work again).  I observed that on the same machine, it failed about 25% of the time on the local loopback.  I'm at a loss as to what to try next, or what could be the problem.

Comment: Did you check IIS logs or try to enable Tracing/Message Logging in WCF?

Comment: @mtheriault  a `self hosted WCF server` doesn't use IIS

Comment: Yeah right... I forgot this part of the issue! ;)

Comment: Not enough details. What's behind ServiceAdmin._AdminVer? Is it a property? field? What's the implementation? I assume ServiceMain is a singleton? Local Property? A full error dump would help too.

Comment: ServiceAdmin._AdminVer is a static field.  So, there's literally nothing it has to do.  There is no error dump.  The client gets the 500 error and the message above that comes with it across the network.

Answer (score -1):

It could be a problem with deadlock error.
It could be a null error, when you try to ask for version that is assign but form other part of the code that value isn't assign.

Full exception message would help more.

But the second one is the most common (imo).

Like you would assign value when asking for /index but you dont assign it on /page. And when you testing you got to /index, but that one time you go to /page directly and boom, exception.